# after post request http respond is 404 not found error in Postman

Tags: spring, postman, http-status-code-404, backend

https://github.com/smollini/youtube-clone1
Backend is starting without any issues, but after sending post request i get 404 not found respond please help.
[Postman screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM5Kv.png)

Comment: Could be the case that the body of the request is missing? That would produce a 404. Check the name and the value of the parameter.